# A derivation of the Normal Distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, ordinary-differential-equations

I was reading the following [article](https://www.sonoma.edu/users/w/wilsonst/papers/Normal/default.html) of a derivation of the Normal Distribution. In the beginning there is the following definition:

> Data are said to be normally distributed if the rate at which the frequencies fall off is proportional to the distance of the score from the mean, and to the frequencies themselves

From this definition, the author gets the following differential equation:
$$\frac{df}{dx}=-k(x-\mu)f(x)$$

What I don't get is that he later says that we can separate the variables in the following form:
$$\frac{df}{f}=-k(x-\mu)~dx$$
I don't understand that part.

Comment: Separation of variables is a standard technique to solve ODE. You may want to read the corresponding article  on Wikipedia :)

Comment: @Ant this one ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables

Comment: Yes that would be a good start